# MS Access Invalid use of Null when performing an insert

Tags: ms-access, null, insert

Using vba, the following insert statement adds new records to a table whenever an attribute (extracted from a smart number) is above a numeric value (6141).  The statement returns an 'Invalid use of null' error.  However, when I just run the select portion, one record is returned and no errors are reported.

```
INSERT INTO tblNewReq 
( [ReqNum], Description, Originator, DateEntered,Title )
SELECT 
cint(Mid([ReferenceID],5)), [Description], 
[Requestor], format([Created],"mm/dd/yyyy"), [ReqTitle]
from [RequestQueue] 
WHERE cint(Mid([ReferenceID],5)) >  6141;
```

Running just the select section returns,
6142, Require cable run, MartinR, 10/31/2016, Network.